# Convert UINT256 to a readable number

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Etherscan shows an ERC-20 contract and this many tokens: 
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000070c96a0ea

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf9d6342d33049fbc9a859af56d9fdd44215b9a6ecaadea0f3d017761de0a3dcb

How do I convert that to a number I can understand?  I can use easily C#, Python, Javascript or is there some type of web converter?

Comment: I just saw that Eitherscan can convert it under "Event Logs": https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf9d6342d33049fbc9a859af56d9fdd44215b9a6ecaadea0f3d017761de0a3dcb#eventlog

Comment: But how many tokens is 30,275,969,258?  Is that Gwei, so divide by 1,000,000,000?

Comment: Turns out I bought about approx 302, so why divided by 100,000??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hexadecimal. In python, `long(your_number, 16)`

Note that because Soldity doesn't support decimals, it's common to multiply by a million or billion or so before storing them on the contract. (The same principle is used with ETH, which the system stores in units of a very small fraction of 1 ETH called Wei.) So you may also need to find out what the contract is multiplying by and divide by that.

Comment: Oh, so each contract basically chooses its own unit of measure then. And the ERC-20 standard does not enforce that?

Comment: The number of decimals is usually given in a function called `decimals()`, but IIUC this isn't strictly part of the standard. https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard